# One to Many Relationship Issue In Getting Sub Details from Main Details with ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-relationship

Good day everyone,

I have sample 2 models with a relationship with each other. One-to-Many relationship

```
// Main model
public class MainDetails {
   [Key]
   public int MainDetailId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public ICollection<SubDetails> SubDetails { get; set; }
}

// Sub model
public class SubDetails {
   [Key]
   public int SubDetailId{ get; set; }
   public string School { get; set; }

   public MainDetails MainDetails { get; set; }
   public int MainDetailId { get; set; }
}
```

Now here's my code where I'm having a problem.

```
public IQuerable<MainDetails> SearchDetails(string school){
     return context.MainDetails.Where(details=>details.SubDetails.School == school) 
     // details.SubDetails.School is an ICollection so this not working.
}

public IQuerable<MainDetails> SearchDetails(string school){
     return context.MainDetails.Inclue(x=>x.SubDetails).Where(details=>details.SubDetails.School == school) 
     // This doesn't work too
}
```

Why I can't be able to get the `SubDetails.School`? or anything to fix this?

Sorry, I'm new when it comes to relationship. I hope you might share me some. Thank you!

Comment: `context.MainDetails.Include(x => x.SubDetails).Where(...`

Comment: I already tried that. But I can't still be able to fetch the School in this sample code `context.MainDetails.Include(x => x.SubDetails).Where(main=>main.SubDetails.School == school)`

Comment: Note also your navigation properties should be `virtual` - refer [Entity Framework Relationships and Navigation Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: But in ASP.NET Core, even without `virtual` relationship will be worked as far as I know sir. @StephenMuecke

Comment: You have not tagged it asp.net-core :)

Comment: Do you have entity relationship configured for `MainDetails` entity type? You need to override method `OnModelCreating` in your context class and add there something like:
`modelBuilder.Entity<MainDetails>().HasMany(x => x.SubDetails);`

Comment: Oh thank you @StephenMuecke for editing it. Yes, I made a wrong. I tagged in ASP.NET Mvc Instead of ASP.NET Core. :)

Comment: @twinmind I'm not using fluent API anyway. I'm using the fully defined relationship find here http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx (Look for Convetion 4)

Comment: @jsonGPPD Your convention for establishing entity relationship looks correct. Do you have tables already created in the database? Could be there is some mismatch between table columns names and entity properties names, maybe casing is different.

Comment: @jsonGPPD Other issue I can imagine is that by default your entity classes names shouldn't be pluralized, so it should be `MainDetail` and `SubDetail` without (s).

Comment: @twinmind yes I already done migration and database update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code shouldn't even be compiling...

```
public IQuerable<MainDetails> SearchDetails(string school)
{
     return context.MainDetails.Where(details=>details.SubDetails.School == school) 
     // details.SubDetails.School is an ICollection so this not working.
}
```

You should need...

```
public IQuerable<MainDetails> SearchDetails(string school)
{
     return context
                .MainDetails
                .Where(details=> 
                    details.SubDetails.Any(sd => sd.School == school));
}
```

Comment: Yes this will work. But my problem is, what if I want to use or call values in my services. like this example `return MainDeatils.Select(details=> new DefaultDetailSelect
            {
                label = details.SubDetails.School
            });`